# xamarin.forms localisation never picks the right language

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to make my app support german and english. I set up the AppResources.resx and a AppResources.de.resx, both files basically look identical:

German one:

```
<root>
    <resheader name="resmimetype">
        <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="version">
        <value>2.0</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="reader">
        <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="writer">
        <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
    </resheader>
       <data name="NotesLabel" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>Notas:</value>
    </data>
    <data name="NotesPlaceholder" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>por ejemplo . comprar leche</value>
    </data>
    <data name="AddButton" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>Agregar nuevo elemento</value>
    </data>
</root>
```

English one:

```
<root>
    <resheader name="resmimetype">
        <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="version">
        <value>2.0</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="reader">
        <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
    </resheader>
    <resheader name="writer">
        <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
    </resheader>
     <data name="AddButton" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>Add Note</value>
    </data>
    <data name="NotesLabel" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>Notes:</value>
    </data>
    <data name="NotesPlaceholder" xml:space="preserve">
        <value>e.g. Get Milk</value>
    </data>
</root>
```

I am then retriving a single string which works fine but it will only ever render the english version, no matter what langaue I set my phone to.

Whan is it that I am missing here?

EDIT:

i have also noticed that changing the assembly langue to : [assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US")]

give me the german texts, even when the phone is set to english ... very confusing

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to add supported languages in your info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>de</string>
    <string>es</string>
    <string>fr</string>
    <string>ja</string>
    <string>pt</string> <!-- Brazil -->
    <string>pt-PT</string> <!-- Portugal -->
    <string>ru</string>
    <string>zh-Hans</string>
    <string>zh-Hant</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
```